# How to use photo in multiple posts?

Tags: images, gallery, featured-post

I have a theme that shows images only from gallery tab
(so i can't re-use an image to other posts). As you know an image can only get attached to 1 post. I found a plugin that you can attach an image to more posts, but it doesn't work for this theme.

to conclude:
I am looking for a way to use the same photo file in more than one post?

thanks ;-)

Comment: What if you unattach the media from the media library, and attach it to the new post ? (this is not very convenient but I was wondering)

Comment: The whole attachment situation precludes you from being able to attach an image to more than one post.  This is the achilles heel of galleries in my opinion.  The File Gallery plugin used to be able to get around that I'm not sure it it still works that way.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the right solution is to find what filter is being used and seeing if it's possible to disable it.

Another: ask the theme author and share the solution here (if answered).

Otherwise, try one of this plugins and see if they override this behavior:

- [Image Pro](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-pro-wordpress-image-media-management-and-resizing-done-right/)
- [Faster Image Insert](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/faster-image-insert/)

Comment: Nice plugins, but doesn't solve the problem.

I already asked the template author and they don't want to change it.